# How to set Tags based azure pipeline stage triggering?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the below Azure YAML pipeline file whose stages get executed based on a tag `some-tag-v*` reference pushed to the Azure repo.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - refs/tags/some-tag-v*
    exclude:
      - refs/tags/some-branch

pool:
  name: some-name
  demands:
  - Agent.Name -equals some-name

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - bash: |
      some-bash-commands
- stage: B
  jobs:
  - job: B
    steps:
    - bash: |
       More-bash-commands
```

**Problem:** I want stage B to be executed only when `some-tag-2-v*` is pushed instead of `some-tag-v*`. I am looking at the condition-based triggering but I am not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I am still developing the script, I will accept the answer today EOD once I test it. Thanks for your answer. I'll be sure to update it asap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you could directly use the [IF Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) in Stages. This will be more convenient.

Here is an example:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - - refs/tags/some-tag-v*
      
    exclude:
      - refs/tags/some-branch


stages:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/some-tag-v') }}:

  - stage: A
    jobs:
    - job: A
      steps:
       - checkout: self
       - bash: echo 1
      
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'some-tag-2-v') }}:

  - stage: B
    jobs:
    - job: B
      steps:
       - bash: echo 2
```

When the pipeline is triggered by some-tag-2-v, it will only run the stage B.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make use of YAML [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions).

```
stages:
- stage: A
  condition: ...
  jobs:
  - job: A
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - bash: |
      some-bash-commands
```

For the condition, you can probably leverage pipeline and build variables, e.g.:

```
variables:
  isSomeTag: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/some-tag-v')]
```

Comment: would it skip stage A and execute only stage B?

Comment: Yes it should, if condition is false.